# Methode return status cancled when using take(1) and when not using it it is lunched multiplit time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

handleRedirect is a method that calls two observable.
the first is ValidateCartService.getValidateCart() with Observable type and the second ValidateCartService.setCart() . once the two methods are triggered and return status 201 it must make a redirect action with this.routingService.go({ cxRoute : 'checkout' }) ;

I've tried using this method. With this form, it is launched several times and the object is launched several times.

```
this.ValidateCartService.getValidateCart().subscribe((Element:any)=>{
        () => {
          this.ValidateCartService.setCart().subscribe((elementCheckout:any)=>{
              this.routingService.go({ cxRoute: 'checkout' });
          })
          ,
        (error) => {
          // Handle errors here
          console.error('Error occurred:', error);
        }
       
        }
      }
      )
```

```
i tried to use this methode it. with this form i get status cancled
```

```
handleRedirect() {
    this.ValidateCartService.getValidateCart().pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(
      (element: any) => {
          this.ValidateCartService.setCart().pipe(
            take(1) 
          ).subscribe(
            (elementCheckout: any) => {
                this.routingService.go({ cxRoute: 'checkout' });
            },
            (errorCheckout: any) => {
              console.error('Error in setDefault information:', errorCheckout);
            }
          );
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
      }
    );
    
  }
```

```
protected validateCartQuery$(
    userId : any,cartId:any
  ): Query<any> {
    return this.queryService.create<any>(
      () =>
        this.ValidateCart.validateCart(
          userId,cartId
        ),
      {
        reloadOn: this.getNavigationEvent(),
        resetOn: this.getNavigationEvent(),
      }
    );
  }

  validateCartState(
    userId : any,cartId:any
  ): any {
    return this.validateCartQuery$(userId,cartId).getState();
  }

  getValidateCart(
  ): any {
    let code : any
    let userId :any
    this.activeCartFacade.getActive().subscribe((cartItem:any)=>{
      code = cartItem.user?.uid === "anonymous"? cartItem.guid : cartItem.code
      userId = cartItem.user?.uid
    })
    return this.validateCartState(userId,code).pipe(
      map((state:any) => state ?? [])
    );
  }
```

this.ValidateCart.validateCart make a call to a config to start a call post with axios and the same for setCart.

Comment: please share the contents of getValidateCart and setCart methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chain the observables which might be the problem, could you please modify the below function?

> use `switchMap` if you need the output of one observable to be used to fetch another observable

```
getValidateCart(): any {
    return this.activeCartFacade.getActive().pipe(
      switchMap((cartItem: any) => {
        const code = cartItem.user?.uid === "anonymous" ? cartItem.guid : cartItem.code;
        const userId = cartItem.user?.uid;
        return this.validateCartState(userId, code).pipe(
          map((state: any) => state ?? [])
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

You can also modify the below function to use `switchMap`(s)

Also [please add subscriptions and unsubscribe on destroy to avoid memory leaks!](https://blogs.halodoc.io/handling-subscription-angular/#:%7E:text=with%20Subscription.,the%20subscription%20assigned%20by%20Subscription.)

```
handleRedirect() {
    this.ValidateCartService.getValidateCart().pipe(
      take(1) // maybe you can remove this?
    ).pipe(
      switchMap((element: any) => {
        return this.ValidateCartService.setCart().pipe(
          take(1)
        ).pipe(
          tap((elementCheckout: any) => {
            this.routingService.go({ cxRoute: 'checkout' });
          })
        ))
    ).subscribe({
      error: (errorCheckout: any) => {
        console.error('Error in setDefault information:', errorCheckout);
      }
    })
  }
```